# How I can get each value of Guid in the loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, guid

I have a list and I want to insert all the value of it with the loop in my SQL. My problem is: I get ever time the same value of Guid I have on the list.

```
JourneyService.ServicePriceId = guidList.OfType<Guid>().FirstOrDefault();
```

I know my problem is .FirstOrDefault() but I don't know what should I do instead of it.

Here all the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < guidList.Count; i++)
{
    JourneyService JourneyService = new JourneyService() ; 
    JourneyService.JourneyServicesId = Guid.NewGuid();
    JourneyService.S1 = i.ToString();
    JourneyService.JourneyId = a;
    JourneyService.ServicePriceId = guidList.OfType<Guid>().FirstOrDefault();
    db.JourneyServices.Add(JourneyService);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looping over `guidList`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < guidList.Count; i++)
```

I would expect that you'd want to use `i` as an indexer for that list:

```
JourneyService.ServicePriceId = guidList[i];
```